# Multi-objective optimization problem - Euclidean space

Tags: algorithms, optimization

I am looking for some clues for an optimization problem.

My problem consists of arriving to a image by optimizing multiple layers with the pixel position probability.

This is an overview of the problem:
[image]

The first image on the left is a zoom of the greyscale image with only two grey values, followed by the probability of each cell taking one value of grey, and the same probability for the value black. Finally, I am looking for a way to arrive to the start image by using only the two layers.

In the end, I will be working with a complete image [like this one](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Grayscale_8bits_palette_sample_image.png):

[image]

I understand that this will not give me a great result and that I need to add constraints to my problem; however, I am completely lost on the subject. I have found a lot of documentation for optimization, but not a good tutorial or examples for optimization problems defined in a Euclidean space. Is there documentation that I could read, a basic tutorial or code examples?

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to what you want when you say you want to treat this as a multi-objective optimization problem. What would be your multiple objective functions?

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of this question in its current form.  Please revise by adding some more examples and discussion, as this looks like an interesting problem.

Comment: Do you have a specific set of cost functions associated with your problem?  Or are you trying to formulate your cost functions and constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should clarify your question a bit more. But the way most optimization problems work is that you need to define a function (cost function) that you need to optimize. Now this function might have multiple parameters or objectives that depend on the problem you are solving. Once you have identified the function, you should use an optimization algorithm to find desired values of the parameters based on the objectives. Some of the methods you can use are Evolutionary Algorithms such as [Differential Evolution](http://www.icsi.berkeley.edu/~storn/code.html), [Genetic Algorithms](http://www.obitko.com/tutorials/genetic-algorithms/) or [Particle Swarm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization). You could also use other gradient based methods about which you can probably find extensive literature via Google. I used the following references during my research on shape optimization in aerodynamics:

- [Differential evolution: a practical approach to global optimization](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Differential_evolution.html?id=S67vX-KqVqUC&redir_esc=y) by Kenneth V. Price, Rainer M. Storn, Jouni A. Lampinen,
- [Differential evolution: in search of solutions](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Differential_evolution.html?id=kG7aP_v-SU4C) by Vitaliy Feoktistov,
- [Global Optimization Algorithms Theory and Application](http://www.it-weise.de) by Thomas Weise.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help @bamdadhosseini! I am new to all these subjects, so the question ended up to be too vague.

Comment: yes, you might want to edit your question again and give us a better idea what you're having trouble with.